# error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" only in IIS

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, iis

I have a project in ASP.NET when I compile and run the project from the visual studio 2019 I didn't get any error and it works perfectly, but when I publish the project and put it on IIS I get the error "**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**".
I searched for the problem and I found the below answer:

***You should put the references to the jquery scripts first.***

My Code:

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.13.0.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.13.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/ajax.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnLog").click(function (e) {
            $("#error").css("visibility", "hidden");;
            $("#loginSpiner").addClass("fa-spin");
            var $form = $("#loginForm");
            var serilzedForm = $form.serialize();
            $("#loginFields").prop("disabled", true);
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Account/login',
                data: serilzedForm,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        if (data.Message || data.InnerException) {
                            $("#loginSpiner").removeClass("fa-spin");
                            $("#error").text(data.Message + "\r\n" + data.InnerException);
                            $("#error").css("visibility", "visible");
                        } else {
                            if (data != null) {
                                if (data.DBUserRights != undefined) {
                                    localStorage["DBUserRights"] = JSON.stringify(data.DBUserRights);
                                }   }
                        }
                    }
                     
                    $("#loginSpiner").removeClass("fa-spin");
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    $("#loginSpiner").removeClass("fa-spin");
                    $("#error").text(err.statusText);
                    $("#error").css("visibility", "visible");
                },
                complete: function (res) {
                    $("#loginSpiner").removeClass("fa-spin");
                    $("#loginFields").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My question is in two parts:

1-What is the difference when I run the project from the visual studio 2019 "without any error" and the IIS (version 10.0.19041.1) "where I faced the problem"?

2- What references should I put in the jquery scripts file?

Comment: What does your event viewer say?

Comment: It shouldn't work in any environment if you load anything that depends on jQuery before you load the jQuery library

Comment: `put the references to the jquery scripts first.` is right. When you want to use a reference to a jquery, you should follow the order of use on the provider's official website. Because HTML is a file loaded from top to bottom. So when you modify the reference does the problem resolve?

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your response, but I call the library of jQuery in the first!

Comment: @BruceZhang Thank you for your response, but I think the error in the image load wherein the publish it didn't load any image and get the error in the part which starts **  $(function () {** (in  above code )

Comment: @JamesS THanks for your response, I open the IIS error log file but I didn't find any text files